# apache camel and cxf

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I want to create cxf webservice and add Camel to transfer received request somewhere else.

And i have question:

If i will use camel-cxf component and configure there webserwice, after deploy camel will send informations to cxf and cxf will create webserwice based on receive configuration ?

Is it works like this ?

Or i need to create webservice in cxf, and additional add configuration in camel, where i will configure webserwice url, and after deploy camel will connect to cxf and will be able to receive request and pass it somewhere else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Camel is simply providing routing to and from a CXF web service. More likely you will want to take a modified approach to your second option. Implement a CXF web service. This accepts either the SOAP or JSON message. In the logic of the web service, send to a bean that is available in the CamelContext. The bean would then contain the logic to route to whatever your "somewhere else" is.

Now, based on your question, it may be that you actually want something closer to a CXF proxy, which you can find more information about on the Camel website.